# Analysing when tunes are alike: testing ordinal and categorical similarity

Tags: categorical-data, ordinal-data

I'd like to compare some Jazz tunes.

Jazz tunes are characterized by a succession of chords. The interval between each succeeding chord (number of tones) and the order in which they appear matter.

At first, I thought of a Mann-Whitney test that could compare two tunes with a different number of chords using the ranks of their intervals.

Another thing matters, though: the quality of the chord. A major chord can follow a minor chord, a dominant one, or a semi-diminished one.  So, there is a mix of ordinal and categorical variables of which to take account.

What methodology should be used in testing the similarity of two jazz tunes?

Comment: Have you tried the default (and generic) way, i.e. calculate MPEG4 descriptors and cluster?

Comment: When people do comparisons of musical pieces for the purposes of information retrieval algorithms, most use [MFCCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum) to decompose the music, rather than doing all of what you describe.

Comment: The analysis is meant to be applied to scores, not recordings.